# Alternative to Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection for Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, remote-desktop

When working from Windows, I prefer to use [RoyalTS](http://code4ward.com/main/RoyalTS/Overview.aspx) instead of the default Microsoft RDP client, because it allows me to save multiple connections, the credentials of the connection, etc; as well has having more than 1 connection open at a time.

Is there a similar (or any) alternative to the [Microsoft RDP client](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/remote-desktop/default.mspx) for connecting from OSX to Windows? Aside from VNC, that is; at this point I'm hoping to continue using the RDP protocol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/) is my pick for RDP access on OS X.

[image]

Comment: Setting this as the accepted answer because of its similarity to my favorite Windows RDP app (RoyalTS). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you can use [TSclientX](http://desktopecho.com/tsclientx/), an alternative to RDP Client for Mac OS X.

[image]

TSclientX is freeware.

Comment: Any diffs in performance?

Comment: @P.Bjorklund Not as far as I can tell. It works just like tsclient on Linux, excellent performance.

Comment: Sorry, this is a decent answer but CoRD is closer to what I was looking for. So just a +1.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that Thinomenon's RDC has the advantage to be compatible with Mac OS X 10.7 Lion when CoRD, TSclientX and apparently Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection are not.

Comment: I'm using CoRD on Lion. Haven't tried it on Mountain Lion.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.thinomenon.com/products/RemoteDesktopClient/osx.aspx is the best RDC client available for free on Mac/Windows/Linux

Comment: When an answer recommends a piece of software, we like that answer to be as detailed as possible. As it currently stands, your answer could be removed due to our quality policy. Please see http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers to learn how to properly recommend software to others :)